# SQL Server password change

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I need to change the SQL Server authentication to a different profile.

I need to create a different user with different permissions. But I have used the old username and password in many SSRS reports. How can I change the same with minimal effort?

Comment: What have you done or tested until now?

Comment: i have created the commonname for login and provide the access as select insert update access to that login. but now i want to restrict that. so i changed the common login to read to mode.

Comment: Did you use a common, external DataSource or lots of individual embedded ones?